# Sending TCP data without recieving (boost asio)

Tags: tcp, boost-asio

I'm working my way through boost's asio tutorial.  I'm looking into their [chat example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html).  More specifically, I'm trying to split their [chat client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/chat/chat_client.cpp) from a sender+receiver, to just a sender and just a receiver, but I'm seeing some behaviour that I can't explain.

The setup consists of:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint = resolver.resolve(...);

boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
boost::asio::async_connect(socket, endpoint, bind(handle_connect, ... ));
```

The sending portion effectively conisists of:

```
while (std::cin.getline(str))
  io_service.post( do_write, str );
```

and

```
void do_write (string str)
{
    boost::asio::async_write(socket, str, bind( handle_write, ... ));
}
```

The receive section consists of

```
void handle_connect(...)
{
    boost::asio::async_read(socket, read_msg_, bind(handle_read, ...));
}

void handle_read(...)
{
    std::cout << read_msg_;
    boost::asio::async_read(socket, read_msg_, bind(handle_read, ...));
}
```

If I comment out the content of `handle_connect` to isolate the send portion, my other client (compiled using the original code) does not receive anything.  If I revert, then comment out the content of `handle_read`, my other client only receives the first message.

Why is it necessary to call `async_read()` in order to be able to `post()` an `async_write()`?

The full unmodified code is linked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that, your `io_service` is running out of work and stops processing requests even before you start sending your chat messages.

If you comment out the body of `handle_connect`, then the only work it had to do was to dispatch the `handle_connect` handler and then execute it once the connection was done.

```
std::size_t scheduler::run(asio::error_code& ec)
{
  .....
  mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex_);

  std::size_t n = 0;
  for (; do_run_one(lock, this_thread, ec); lock.lock())
    if (n != (std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max)())
      ++n;
  return n;
}
```

So, you have to provide it with something in it's operation queue. This was done with `handle_read_header` handler in the original code as this handler would always be in the need of servicing till the client gets something from the server.

You can do what you want to do by providing `work` to the `io_service`.

```
asio::io_context io_context;
asio::io_context::work wrk(io_context); // make `run` run forever

tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
tcp::resolver::results_type endpoints = resolver.resolve(argv[1], argv[2]);

chat_client c(io_context, endpoints);

asio::thread t(boost::bind(&asio::io_context::run, &io_context));
```

Comment: You were absolutely right.  I added the work to the io_service and it works great.  Thanks!